# Updating Database with Index-Match (VBA)

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop, indexing, match

I have an important question. I have a small data table (filtered table) and my big database (about 23'000 rows). Structures are the same. I want to update the database qty (column 4 in sheet2) with the remaining quantity (column 5 in sheet1) of the filtered table to see the current status of the stock.

Pictures:
[Filtered Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQyJj.png) and [Small part of the Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kR98V.png)

I use the index-match-function. Only if the product code AND the delivery number matches (unique) then update the matched row by changing the quantity of the DB with the remaining quantity of the filtered table.

```
Sub UpdateDB()

On Error Resume Next
Dim Dept_Row As Long
Dim Dept_Clm As Long

lastrow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Worksheets.Count).Cells(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Worksheets.Count).Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
lastrowA = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Worksheets.Count).Cells(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Worksheets.Count).Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
lastrowI = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row 
lastrowG = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row 

table1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Worksheets.Count).Range("C2:C" & lastrow) 
table2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Worksheets.Count).Range("A2:D" & lastrowA) 
table3 = Sheet1.Range("I2:I" & lastrowI)
table4 = Sheet1.Range("G2:K" & lastrowG)

Dept_Clm = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Worksheets.Count).Range("B2").Column
Dept_Row = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Worksheets.Count).Range("B2").Row


'Checking for delivery numbers of the filtered table and the new sheet and updating the corresponding remaining quantity
For Each dl In table3
DLfiltered = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(table4, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(dl, table3, 0), 3)
DLnewdb = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(table2, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(dl, table1, 0), 3)

pcfiltered = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(table4, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(dl, table3, 0), 1)
pcnewdb = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(table2, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(dl, table1, 0), 1)

remainqty = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(table4, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(dl, table3, 0), 5)
Row = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(dl, table1, 0)


'If the delivery numbers and the product codes are the same, then update quantity
If dlnewdb = dlfiltered And pcfiltered = pcnewdb Then
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Worksheets.Count).Cells(Dept_Row, Dept_Clm) = remainqty
End If

Next CDN

End Sub
```

I know something is missing in the ELSE part of the IF-Function. If it cannot find a match, it just jumps to the next delivery number and ignores the row. But it should search until it is found.

Any advice for this case please?

Comment: @Om3r, what do you think? Is there any good solution for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved. I just changed the range of the for-loop. It was a logical error.

Range is:

```
table6 = Sheet1.Range("G2:G" & lastrowG)
```

Abdul